# Centrality Measures in a Weighted Network using Statnet in R

Tags: r, igraph, weighted-graph, statnet

I created a weighted network using both igraph and statnet in R. I am now studying centrality measures of my weighted network using statnet, but the centrality measures I obtain are as if statnet did not take into account the values of my edges.
Here is a small example to illustrate my problem, using the degree centrality measure.

I created my network using igraph:

```
nodes <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5))
edges <- data.frame(source=c(1,1,2,2,3),
                    target=c(2,3,3,5,4),
                    weight=c(1,2,1,2,1)) 
library(igraph)
network <- graph_from_data_frame(d=edges, vertices=nodes, directed=FALSE)
```

Then I needed to use the statnet package so I transformed it the following way

```
  network_statnet <- asNetwork(network)
  detach("package:igraph", unload=TRUE)
  library(statnet)
```

Then I wanted to compute the degree centrality, first without taking the edges values into account (`degree_unweighted`), and then taking the edges values into account (`degree_weighted`)

```
degree_unweighted<-degree(network_statnet, gmode="graph", ignore.eval=TRUE)
degree_weighted<-degree(network_statnet, gmode="graph", ignore.eval=FALSE)
```

But I end up with exaclty the same centrality measures. I do not know why statnet does not take into account the values of my edges when I specify `ignore.eval=FALSE`. I have the same problem with other centrality measures (betweenness, closeness, eigenvector).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, `degree` ignores weights regardless of `ignore.eval`. It is visible in the very first line of `degree` where we have

```
dat <- as.edgelist.sna(dat)
```

while `as.edgelist.sna` has a parameter `attrname`:

> attrname - if x is a network object, the (optional) edge attribute to
>   be used to obtain edge values.

So `degree` actually doesn't even seem to try to use any weights. As to fix that, we may redefine this function by adding a possibility to use weights as in

```
myDegree <- function (dat, g = 1, nodes = NULL, gmode = "digraph", diag = FALSE, 
          tmaxdev = FALSE, cmode = "freeman", rescale = FALSE, ignore.eval = FALSE, attrname = NULL) 
{
  dat <- as.edgelist.sna(dat, attrname = attrname)
  if (is.list(dat)) 
    return(sapply(dat[g], degree, g = 1, nodes = nodes, gmode = gmode, 
                  diag = diag, tmaxdev = tmaxdev, cmode = cmode, rescale = rescale))
  n <- attr(dat, "n")
  if (gmode == "graph") 
    cmode <- "indegree"
  if (tmaxdev) {
    if (gmode == "digraph") 
      deg <- switch(cmode, indegree = (n - 1) * (n - 1 + 
                                                   diag), outdegree = (n - 1) * (n - 1 + diag), 
                    freeman = (n - 1) * (2 * (n - 1) - 2 + diag))
    else deg <- switch(cmode, indegree = (n - 1) * (n - 2 + 
                                                      diag), outdegree = (n - 1) * (n - 2 + diag), freeman = (n - 
                                                                                                                1) * (2 * (n - 1) - 2 + diag))
  }
  else {
    m <- NROW(dat)
    cm <- switch(cmode, indegree = 0, outdegree = 1, freeman = 2)
    if (!(cmode %in% c("indegree", "outdegree", "freeman"))) 
      stop("Unknown cmode in degree.\n")
    deg <- .C("degree_R", as.double(dat), as.integer(m), 
              as.integer(cm), as.integer(diag), as.integer(ignore.eval), 
              deg = as.double(rep(0, n)), PACKAGE = "sna", NAOK = TRUE)$deg
    if (rescale) 
      deg <- deg/sum(deg)
    if (!is.null(nodes)) 
      deg <- deg[nodes]
  }
  deg
}
```

This then gives

```
(degree_unweighted <- myDegree(network_statnet, gmode = "graph", ignore.eval = TRUE))
# [1] 2 3 3 1 1
(degree_weighted <- myDegree(network_statnet, gmode = "graph", ignore.eval = FALSE, attrname = "weight"))
# [1] 3 4 4 1 2
```

I'm afraid you are going to need the same adjustment for other functions such as `betweenness`.

Comment: This actually sounds like a bug of `sna::degree`. This should be notified to the Statnet team. Unfortunately, it seems that they are not actively working on sna these days.